# A trigonometric expression with the angles being in Arithmetic progression

Tags: trigonometry

### Prove that $$\cot\theta\cot2\theta +\cot2\theta\cot3\theta +2 = \cot\theta(\cot\theta -\cot3\theta)$$

Well I have already proved it by expresing in terms of sin and cos and taking it from there

I wish to be enlightened with a better solution

Answer (score 1):

Hint use $\cot(a-b)=\frac{1+\cot(a)\cot(b)}{\cot(a)-\cot(b)}$ express lhs as sum of two cots to get rhs

Comment: Awesome!!!.That is way shorter than what I did